# Нужно ли выбрасывать исключение в этом случае?

Tags: php, ооп

На сайте есть личный кабинет, при авторизации, в сессию записывается ID текущего пользователя.

Сейчас разрабатываем класс для работы с сущностью Пользователь `User`, в котором будут методы работы с пользователем, `getName(), getId(), ...`

В конструкторе класса делается выборка из БД по ID текущего пользователя.

Что делать, если другие разработчики пользуясь этим классом, будут случайно использовать, когда еще пользователь неавторизован и нет ID пользователя ?

Нужно лди в конструкторе класса проверять на существование ID (авторизован или нет) и выбрасывать исключение ? 
Иначе придется в каждом методе класса  кучу проверок делать.

Что делают в таких случаях, когда класс работает должен работать с сущньостию, которого нет? это исключительная ситуация или нет? Или нужно у всех методов класса возвращать false/null?

Comment: В первую очередь нужно проверять авторизацию (в конструкторе), а по-хорошему надо брать любой фреймворк со всеми готовыми плюшками, а не писать очередное творение. Лучше написать отдельный exception handler для этого дела, а не просто возвращать ошибку

Comment: у вас небось из сессии берется айди в конструкторе?

Comment: @Ипатьев да.
Я понял. Передаю по конструктору и нет проблем ?))

Comment: проблемы только начинаются

Comment: @Ипатьев а именно?

Answer (score 4):

Надо просто не валить все в кучу.

Есть такой прекрасный принцип, Single responsibility principle. Он говорит нам о том, что каждый класс должен заниматься только своим делом. А не быть винегретом из сессий, авторизации, имени пользователя и его онлайн контактов.

Поэтому сама по себе сущность Пользователь вообще ничего не должна знать про авторизацию. Именно по той причине, что Пользователь и Авторизация - это две разные сущности, имеющие между собой мало общего. Про ессии она тем более ничего должна знать. Класс Пользователь должен содержать информацию о пользователе и больше ни о чем.

С какой стати вы вообще решили, что пользователь в системе бывает только один - авторизованный? А если надо вывести список его друзей? А если рядом с каждой статьей надо выводить информацию об авторе?

Дла авторизации надо использовать класс Авторизация или Текущий Пользователь или как угодно, но только не Пользователь. И вот этот уже класс будет отвечать за авторизацию. И уже этот класс должен получать информацию о пользователе из сессии.